PostgresSQL Разделение столбца на строки по заданному признаку
хотел бы уточнить, какую функцию использовать в PostgresSQL для следующей задачи. Есть таблица вида:
NAME    VALUES
--------------
MIKE    2, 4, 6
NICK    1, 4

Каждому имени соответствуют какие-то значения. Я бы хотел создать VIEW (или просто запрос), в которой эти значения разделяются в отдельные строки по признаку разделения запятая пробел, а именно:
NAME    VALUE
-------------
MIKE    2
MIKE    4
MIKE    6
NICK    1
NICK    4

Прошу, пожалуйста, подсказать, как можно это сделать.

Ну вообще-то лучше и правильнее изменить структуру хранения, и перейти от CSV к нормализованной структуре, вот той, что нужно получить в итоге. как можно это сделать UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(values, ','))::INT

Да, спасибо, функция UNNEST сработала отлично! То, что нужно.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kJxcVbDexMpN5ukBAStcKG/0
